# Illustrate ECC group

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to get a drawing like this in tikz, illustrating an Elliptic Curve group's binary operator.

[image: ECC]

I get the curve equation with a single controlling parameter `t` as `(x,y)=(t^2,t(t^2-a))` (here with `a=3` and `t` from `-2.1` to `2.1`), and can compute `t"` for `P"` as `(t*t'+a)/(t+t')`, with the unmarked point `-t"`.

Update: I kicked me started and get the following, but

- I did not manage to use my parametric equation with *t* the controlling variable
- I don't know how to proceed to define my points and draw a line (I could get their `(x,y)` coordinates but then?). If only I knew where I declare variables, and how I use them to plot!
- my node `[left=15mm, below=2mm,black]` is entirely empirical and super brittle.

Update: `t=-3/5`, `t'=-7/5`, `t"=-48/25` would do.

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[tb]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=0, xmax=4.5,
        ymin=-2.5, ymax=2.5,
        xlabel={$x$}, ylabel={$y$},
        domain=0:4.2, samples=400,
        scale only axis, axis lines=middle,
        smooth, axis equal image=true, clip=true,
    ]
        \addplot [thick,purple] {sqrt((x-3)^2*x)}
            node[left=15mm, below=2mm,black] {$y^2=x(x-3)^2$};
        \addplot [thick,purple] {-sqrt((x-3)^2*x)};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{What I get}
\label{firstfig}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I get]

Comment: what are the values of `t` and `t'` do you want?

Comment: @Black Mild: `t=-3/5`, `t'=-7/5`, giving `t"=-48/25` would do. If they can be changed, that's best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With avaiable parameter equations of EEC, I use TikZ for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,declare function={
a=3; 
t1=-1.5;
t2=-.5;
t3=(t1*t2+a)/(t1+t2);       
x(\t)=(\t)^2;         % do not use \t^2
y(\t)=\t*((\t)^2-a);    
}]
\clip (-.5,-2.5) rectangle (4.5,2.5);
\draw[->] (-.5,0)--(4.5,0) node[below left]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-2.5)--(0,2.5) node[below left]{$y$};
\draw[magenta,smooth,thick] plot[variable=\t,domain=-2.1:2.1] ({x(\t)},{y(\t)}) node[left=15mm, below=4mm]{$y^2=x(x-3)^2$};

\path 
(0,0) node[below left]{O}
({x(t1)},{y(t1)}) coordinate (P) node[above right]{$P$}
({x(t2)},{y(t2)}) coordinate (Pp) node[below right]{$P'$}
({x(t3)},{y(t3)}) coordinate (Ppp) node[right]{$P''$};

\draw[shorten >=-1cm,shorten <=-2cm] (P)--(Pp);
\draw (Ppp)--+(90:2.5) (Ppp)--+(-90:1.5);
\fill[red] (P) circle(2pt); 
\fill[blue] (Pp) circle(2pt);
\fill (Ppp) circle(2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, the Rosetta Stone!